# deb package building

Tags: package-management, source-packages

While trying to build a package, I gave the following command in terminal:

```
cd Downloads/src/
cd unity-5.10.0/
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
```

Then it gives the output:

```
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
dpkg-buildpackage: source package unity
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 5.10.0-0ubuntu6
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Didier Roche <didrocks@ubuntu.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture i386
dpkg-source --before-build unity-5.10.0
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: libutouch-grail-dev (>= 1.0.20) libutouch-geis-dev (>= 2.0.10)
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: Build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting.
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
```

Then I tried to install the package using:

```
cd..
sudo dpkg -i *deb
```

And it gives:

```
[sudo] password for harshnarang8: 
dpkg: error processing *deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
*deb
```

What is exactly causing the problem and how to encounter it?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you building on? Why are you trying to build unity-5.10 specifically?

Comment: I am using 12.04 LTS and Actually i wanted to change the look of the notification bar. So i wanted to change the source.

Comment: Ok you could try a newer Unity, the latest Unity version is 5.20.0 for 12.04 LTS http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/unity

Comment: I tried installing the packages as you suggested. It works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: libutouch-grail-dev (>= 1.0.20) libutouch-geis-dev (>= 2.0.10)
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: Build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting.
```

libutouch-grail-dev is one of the build dependencies, but you have not installed it. Do:

```
apt-get build-dep unity
```

Your second error happens because the package build failed, so you do not have a built package. You can not install a package that you do not have.

Comment: on using the command:
'sudo apt-get build-dep unity'
nothing gets downloaded.

Comment: `apt-get build-dep unity` on a fresh 14.04 system will install 162 packages. Perhaps you already installed them? It looks like you are trying to build an old version of Unity, and it has a bug causing the build dependencies to be incomplete. Build a more recent version of Unity, or satisfy the dependencies manually (`apt-get install libutouch-grail-dev libutouch-geis-dev`)